# Trouble with Sensor Listeners and Ambient mode in Android Wear fragments

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors

I have an app that uses sensor listeners in fragments to detect shaking gestures on a Moto360 smartwatch. Each fragment has a different set of gestures so must register/unregister it's listeners from the sensor manager when it is opened/closed. Everything works fine until the watch goes into ambient mode. Once the app returns from ambient mode the sensors start to malfunction or stop working altogether. I suspect I may be handling the registering/unregistering incorrectly. Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

I have a MainWearActivity class which extends WearableActivity and handles all the fragment transactions:

```
public class MainWearActivity extends WearableActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_wear);
        setAmbientEnabled();
        // ... etc ...//
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnterAmbient(Bundle ambientDetails) {
        super.onEnterAmbient(ambientDetails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdateAmbient() {
        super.onUpdateAmbient();
    }

    @Override
    public void onExitAmbient() {
        super.onExitAmbient();
    }

    // Method the main fragment uses to replace itself with a new fragment
    public void replaceFragment(Fragment frag, String fragTag) {
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, frag, fragTag);
        mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        mFragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

I have a main fragment which presents a menu to the user and allows them to choose an option. When the user chooses an option, the main fragment is placed on the backstack and replaced by the option fragment. When the user returns from the option fragment, the backstack is popped to return to the main menu fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainWearActivity mMainWearActivity;
    View view;

    private SensorManager mSensorMgr;
    private WearXFlick mXFlick; //Extends SensorEventListener
    private Vibrator vibrator;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMainWearActivity = (MainWearActivity) getActivity();
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mMainWearActivity.getSystemService(Activity.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mXFlick = new WearXFlick();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mSensorMgr.registerListener(mXFlick, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

        mXFlick.setOnShakeListener(new OnShakeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShake() {
                vibrator.vibrate(Consts.vibPattern, -1);
                // Select the current menu item
                switch (mMainWearActivity.getCurrentSelection()) {
                    case Consts.MENU_MAIL:
                        MailFragment mf = new MailFragment();
                        mMainWearActivity.replaceFragment(mf, Consts.FRAG_MAIL);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(mXFlick);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mSensorMgr.registerListener(mXFlick, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(mXFlick);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorMgr.registerListener(mXFlick, mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(mXFlick);
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
}
```

Once replaceFragment() is called, a new fragment is loaded which basically has the same format as this, where a different set of sensor listeners are registered and unregistered on stop/start/pause/resume, although I really don't know if that's the correct way I should be unregistering/registering the sensor listeners. It all works fine, though, until the app goes into ambient mode and returns. When that happens, the sensors malfunction or fail.

Comment: I'd love to get an answer to this too.  When AmbientMode starts, I find all the sensors stop.